# Find and remove elements from list, while retaining the location for later insertion

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using the following in Python 2.7:

```
dfile = 'new_data.txt'   #  Depth file no. 1
d_row = [line.strip() for line in open(dfile)]
```

I have loaded a data file into a list without the newline character. Now I want to index all elements within d_row where the beginning of the string is not numeric and/or empty. Next, I require:

1. removal of all of the above detailed non-numeric instances and
2. save the strings and indexes for later insertion into an updated file.

Example of data:

```
Thu Mar 14 18:17:05 2013                                                       
Fri Mar 15 01:40:25 2013

FT

DepthChange: 0.000000,2895.336,0.000
1363285025.250000,9498.970
1363285025.300000,9498.970
1363285026.050000,9498.970
1363287840.450042,9458.010
1363287840.500042,9458.010
1363287840.850042,9458.010
1363287840.900042,9458.010
DepthChange: 0.000000,2882.810,9457.200
1363287840.950042,9458.010
DepthChange: 0.000000,2882.810,0.000
1363287841.000042,9457.170
1363287841.050042,9457.170
1363287841.100042,9457.170
1363287841.150042,9457.170
1363287841.200042,9457.170
1363287841.250042,9457.170
1363287841.300042,9457.170
1363291902.750102,9149.937
1363291902.800102,9149.822
1363291902.850102,9149.822
1363291902.900102,9149.822
1363291902.950102,9149.822
1363291903.000102,9149.822
1363291903.050102,9149.708
1363291903.100102,9149.708
1363291903.150102,9149.708
1363291903.200102,9149.708
1363291903.250102,9149.708
1363291903.300102,9149.592
1363291903.350102,9149.592
1363291903.400102,9149.592
1363291903.450102,9149.592
1363291903.500102,9149.592
DepthChange: 0.000000,2788.770,2788.709
1363291903.550102,9149.479
1363291903.600102,9149.379
```

I have been doing the removal step manually which is time consuming because the file contains over half a million rows. Currently I am unable to rewrite the file containing all of the original elements with some modifications.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, you aren't closing your input file. While this isn't as bad as leaking output files, it's still bad. You should almost never use `open` anywhere but in a `with` statement unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: can you say more about the merge process? one thing to be careful about is of course that if you delete rows, indexes of lines after the deleted line change. there are a few ways to solve that problem, but not clear exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfile = 'new_data.txt'
with open(dfile) as infile:
  numericLines = set() # line numbers of lines that start with digits
  emptyLines = set() # line numbers of lines that are empty
  charLines = [] # line numbers of lines that start with a letter
  for lineno, line in enumerate(infile):
    if line[0].isalpha:
      charLines.append(line.strip())
    elif line[0].isdigit():
      numericLines.add(lineno)
    elif not line.strip():
      emptyLines.add(lineno)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is in two passes: First get the lines and line numbers of the non-matching lines, and then get the lines of the matching lines.

```
d_rows = [line.strip() for line in open(dfile)]
good_rows = [(i, row) for i, row in enumerate(d_rows) if is_good_row(row)]
bad_rows = [(i, row) for i, row in enumerate(d_rows) if not is_good_row(row)]
```

This does mean making two passes over the list, but who cares? If the list is small enough to read the whole thing into memory as you're already doing, the extra cost is probably negligible.

Alternatively, if you need to avoid the cost of building two lists in two passes, you probably also need to avoid reading the whole file at once in the first place, so you'll have to do things a little more cleverly:

```
d_rows = (line.strip() for line in open(dfile)) # notice genexp, not list comp
good_rows, bad_rows = [], []
for i, row in enumerate(d_rows):
    if is_good_row(row):
        good_rows.append((i, row))
    else:
        bad_rows.append((i, row))
```

If you can push things even farther back to the point where you don't even need explicit `good_rows` and `bad_rows` lists, you can keep everything in an iterator all the way through, and waste no memory or up-front reading time at all:

```
d_rows = (line.strip() for line in open(dfile)) # notice genexp, not list comp
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for i, row in enumerate(d_rows):
        if is_good_row(row):
            f.write(row + '\n')
        else:
            whatever_you_wanted_to_do_with(i, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied to my question. Using a part of each reply I was able to attain the desired result.  What finally worked is as follows:

```
goodrow_ind, badrow_ind, badrows = [], [], []

d_rows = (line for line in open(ifile))
with open(ofile, 'w') as f:
    for i, row in enumerate(d_rows):
        if row[0].isdigit():
            f.write(row)
            goodrow_ind.append((i))
        else:
            badrow_ind.append((i))
            badrows.append((row))

ifile.close()

data = np.loadtxt(open(ofile,'rb'),delimiter=',')
```

The result is  "good" and "bad" rows separated with an index for each.